# Can I replace a 2.80 HP Treadmill Motor with 3.60 HP both @130 VDC?

Tags: dc-motor

Is it ok to use the 3.60 HP motor to replace the broken 2.60 HP motor in my treadmill?  If not why?

Old Dead 
2.60 HP Cont Duty @110 VDC/1939 Watts

[image]

New Replacement 
- Will this work with the original Treadmill controller? 
3.60 HP Cont Duty @110 VDC/2685 Watts

[image]

Board: ICON MC1618DLS
Controller: 386762-HH63W119978

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to post a picture of the motor controller circuit? What is the AC line fuse for the treadmill?

Comment: Added controller.  Could not find a fuse.

Comment: Using two IRFP250M...you should be fine. As Tony Stewart said, as long as you don't start the motor at top speed, or have someone too heavy for too long using it, it should be fine. The controller is made for handling both motors.

Comment: The motors state different fans though so you may need to check.

Answer (score 3):

If the controller is still OK, and you don't stall the motor on full startup, I would expect no problems for normal use.